# Java Interceptor not working on web service app

Tags: java, interceptor

I have my app in Java Spring, and I cannot make the interceptors work. 
The idea of the interceptor is to check if the token is still valid.

Below you have the code:

Interceptor class:

```
@Interceptor
public class SessionInterceptor {

@Autowired
LoginDao loginDao;

public SessionInterceptor(){}

@AroundInvoke
public Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    Response response = new Response();
    Object[] parameters = context.getParameters();
    if(parameters.length > 0 && parameters[0] instanceof HttpServletRequest){
        HttpServletRequest jwt = (HttpServletRequest) parameters[0];
        String token = JWTTokenAuthFilter.getToken(jwt);
        if(token != null && this.loginDao.isTokenValid(JWTTokenAuthFilter.getToken(jwt))){
            return context.proceed();
        }
        else
            response.failed(CodeList.SESSION_TIME_OUT);
    }
    else
        response.failed(CodeList.NOT_ALLOWED);
    return response;
}
}
```

And this is how I'm using it in the User class

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    @Interceptors(SessionInterceptor.class)
    public Response add(HttpServletRequest request, UserEnrollmentBO s) throws Exception {
        Response response = new Response();
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }
```

I also added to the spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="sessionInterceptor" class="com.app.security.SessionInterceptor" />
```

Am I missing something?